# Displaying JSON within Datatables from a URL

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatables, jsonp

I am attempting to display 3 pieces of information from the [NordVPN API](https://nordvpn.com/api/server) within a table which is using the datatables plug-in. To be specific I am wanting to display the following three options;

- **Domain** *"domain":"cl1.nordvpn.com"*
- **Country** *"country":"Chile"*
- **Load** *"load":57*

I have been doing some research, and I believe I need to use JSONP due to the fact I am trying to pull data from a remote domain. The following is where I am up to;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Domain</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Load</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "https://nordvpn.com/api/server",
                "dataType": "jsonp"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have successfully managed to display data but I had to firstly parse the JSON and add `"data": [` into that parsed JSON in order for it to work, which in this case is not going to work. I am starting to feel like I am either doing this completely wrong, or its not going to be possible therefore I would appreciate some advice, thank you.

Comment: have a look at the `dataSrc` option (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc), I've been playing here and I can't even get that far TBH but good luck!